# The shade equation of a slanted light projected onto a sphere.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=1$ be a sphere in $\Bbb R^3$. $z=0$ be as a ground. Suppose a light source is located at $(d,0,d)$ ($d>0$). As $d\to\infty$, it is assumed that the light can be view as "parallel" light. Find the equation of the shade on the ground.

I have totally no idea about this. (I'd tried use the slanted cylinder equation, or tangent plane to the spheres, but still stuck on it. )Need help!

Comment: What is the inclination of light rays wrt ground? What shape does a shadow of a circle look like?

Comment: Could you give a name to this shape ?

Comment: @cosmo5 $45$ degree? Not sure if it is an ellipse.

Comment: @JeanMarie Ellipse? I'm pretty not sure.

Comment: You are right. Therefore you only have to find the endpoints of its semimajor and semiminor axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the intersection of your sphere with the $XZ$-plane. This is a circle of radius $1$ tangent to the $X$ axis. The two rays of light coming from infinity under a $45$ degrees angle are tangent to that circle at the points $(\sqrt{2}/2,0,1-\sqrt{2}/2)$ and $(-\sqrt{2}/2,0,1+\sqrt{2}/2)$ (just draw a picture to convince yourself). Those two lines have direction vector $(1,0,1)$ so their equations are
$$
(x,y,z)=(\sqrt{2}/2,0,1-\sqrt{2}/2)+t(1,0,1),\quad (x,y,z)=(-\sqrt{2}/2,0,1+\sqrt{2}/2)+t(1,0,1)
$$
They intersect the $XY$ plane at $(\sqrt{2}-1,0,0)$ and $(-\sqrt{2}-1,0,0)$. Those are the endpoints of the major axis, so the center is at $(-1,0,0)$ and $a=\sqrt{2}$. Clearly, $b=1$ (no deformation in that direction). The equation of the shadow on the $XY$-plane is
$$
\frac{(x+1)^2}{2}+y^2=1
$$

Comment: Thanks! pretty clear! By the way, is there a clear and rigorous way to know that the shade is an ellipse?

Comment: Any section of a circular cylinder is an ellipse.